# Whats the best way to list out all custom taxonomies in Wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, custom-taxonomy

Ok so I have a custom taxonomy called "Types" for a custom post type of "Products". Now I have a lot of different "types" for that custom post type. I want to list out all of the different types with a link to those specific types that displays all of the products assigned to those specific types.

I know of `wp_list_categories` which is great but can I use it for custom taxonomies and not just the default Wordpress category taxonomy? Is there another way or a better way of listing all of my custom taxonomies that give me the ability to list out all or certain types?

Quick example of how I would want to see my list of custom taxonomies:

Types:

- Sweet(1)
- Sour(4)
- Spicy(7)
- Hot(2)

Comment: [wp_list_categories()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories) has a `taxonomy` argument

Comment: so you can list out custom taxonomies just as you would the regular category? or is it limited?

Comment: Do all of the categories you're trying to list exist under the same taxonomy?

Comment: For example, do `sweet, sour, spicy, hot` all exist under the same taxonomy?

Comment: Yes all under the taxonomy of "Types" and they have sub-categories as well.

Comment: So can you not do `wp_list_categories( array( 'taxonomy' => 'Types' ) );`?

Comment: But would I have the option of selecting only certain types or sub categories?

Comment: You can choose a `depth`...so yes. Alternatively, there's always the manual way, using [get_categories()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories)

Comment: really thought wp_list_categories was just for the default wordpress categories taxonomy. Did not know you could use it for custom taxonomies as well.